# Stripping out words in street names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following addresses, and I need to strip out only the actual street names

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Address varchar(100)    
)

INSERT INTO @T (Address, Desired) VALUES
('Unit 5, 10-16 Smith Street'),
('180 Long Hill Road'),
('318 Great East Build Road'),
('50 Angus Street'),
('103 Inch Street'),
('Unit 1, 28A State Road')
```

Expected results:

```
Smith Street
Long Hill Road
Great East Build Road
Angus Street
Inch Street
State Road
```

How could this be done?

I have this so far, and it is nearly there, but it is returning Road as Roa and Street and as Street:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(
            TRIM(
                REPLACE(
                    SUBSTRING(
                        @String, 
                        CHARINDEX(',', @String), 
                        LEN(@String)
                    ), 
                    ',', 
                '')
            ), 
            CHARINDEX(' ', 
                TRIM(
                    REPLACE(
                        SUBSTRING(
                            @String, 
                            CHARINDEX(',', @String), 
                            LEN(@String)
                        )
                    , ',', '')
                )
            ) +0, 
            205
        )
```

Comment: Is the street name always the last thing on the address? Can you have street names that contain numbers like `the 6th Avenue`? Also, what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? With 500 reputation points I would expect you already know [ask]...

Comment: Sorry yes, there could be for example Unit 1, 28A State Road

Comment: Well, that can be quite a pickle. Are these addresses all in the same state, at least?

Comment: Sorry yes, I've modified my question. I'm nearly there with a query but missing the final character,

Comment: I've edited your question to show sample data and desired results properly, so that when people attempt to answer it, they can copy the sample data to a test environment and try their answers before posting. Please always post sample data as DDL and DML statements when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Your desired output conflicts with sample data. You want "28A State Road" but not "10-16 Smith Street". **YOU** might know that "28A" is the part of the actual name but I cannot see logic that will differentiate between them. Are you certain that 28A is part of the street name? That seems a little suspect. I would expect something like "Route 28A". Other examples I can think of are: "Hwy 41", "SR 41", "SR A1A", "US 1", "County Road 728". That last one is very common in rural areas btw.

Comment: Sorry @SMor, I can't believe I had that typo. It definitely shouldn't show 28A because that is a Street/Unit Number. It should only show "State Road". My bad big time, in the best interests, should I accept this answer, and raise a new question?

Comment: In actual fact SMor, @Zohar Peled introduced that incorrect test case. It wasn't in my original question.

Comment: It wasn't in your original question but you did include it later in the comments - and this is an important example since it shows that street names can also contain numbers.

Comment: I doubt there is any possible logic that will work correctly without a consistent format.  You might try multiple passes of logic. Remove the first part for those having a comma. After that, who can say without a more in-depth analysis of your data.

Answer (score 1):

```
select street into #tab from (
    select 'unit 5, 10-16 Smith Street' as street
    union all select '180 Long Hill Street'
    union all select '103 Inch Street') t

select
    reverse(rev) street,
    reverse(substring(rev,1,PATINDEX('%[^0-9][0-9]%',rev)))
from
    (select reverse(street) as rev from #tab) t

drop table #tab
```

Comment: It'll be nicer to take advantage of LTRIM and RTRIM to handle the extra white spaces, and CASE to handle the unit number (28A). This will give a cleaner results.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for all those test cases as per @iSR5 comment. Can you please adjust? There are many different addresses so can't hard-code 28A.

Comment: @Philip You are contradicting yourself. Your desired results has 28A as part of a street name. Now you say it is a unit number. Do you know with certainty what the correct result is for this case? "State Street" (or Road) is a rather common street name.

Comment: Sorry @SMor, I can't believe I had that typo. It definitely shouldn't show 28A because that is a Street/Unit Number. It should only show "State Road". My bad big time, in the best interests, should I accept this answer, and raise a new question?

Comment: In actual fact SMor, @Zohar Peled introduced that incorrect test case. It wasn't in my original question.